# Force.com IDE V2 new SFDX project w/ embedded space in project location directory name - fails to create

Tags: force.com-ide, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Detail Description: 
To get a hands on on Force.com IDE 2, I installed it on my system. But while creating a project it gives me below error. This error is becoz of white space in the project path.

[image]

As it is clear in the picture the error is due to white space in my project name path.
I checked & found that in CMD & in Powershell, I can avoid this error using either single quote, double quote or escaping space character.

[image]

But no success. Salesforce Force.com ide 2 does not work with any above workaround. I m not able to create new Salesforce dx project as project lie in a directory with space in name.

Let me know, if anyone faced this issue earlier & how we can fix it.

Thanks in Advance.

P.S.: Question updated as got negative response (i.e. question is not clear). Be kind & let us know what is not clear. Just giving negative response & going away won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a project using force.com IDE with a long path name with space in the name. I am able to create the project without any issue. See attached screenshot.I selected the folder name using the browse button. [image: SFDX Project created with space in the name]

Comment: Well I am using 64 bit version of Force.com IDE& is still facing the same error. 
> Checked there was no new update too. 
Which version of Force.com IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using 64 bit version of Force.com IDE too.

Comment: Hmm.. Its weird. As i shown in screenshot, i am still getting same error.